# Tuple() on GenExp vs. ListComp

Tags: python, performance, list, tuples

I have a list of some (small number) of items, eg:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and I have a tuple of indexes, eg:

```
indexes = (1,5,9)
```

I want the *tuple* of the values from the list, eg:

```
tuple(my_list[x] for x in indexes)
```

but this is proving to be quite slow (when run many many times).

The tuple of indexes doesn't change for each list I run this over - so is there a faster way?

I'm using Python 2.5, and I get these surprising results so far:

```
python -m timeit -s "indexes = (1,5,9); l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" "tuple(l[i] for i in indexes)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.02 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "indexes = (1,5,9); l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" "tuple([l[i] for i  in indexes])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.707 usec per loop
```

Is this an anomaly, or is the list comprehension really that much better than the generator expression?

Comment: What exactly is the output you're looking for? I don't completely understand your question.

Comment: @sdamashek he's asking why calling `tuple` on a genexp is much slower than calling `tuple` on a list comp

Comment: I'm also asking if there's a better/faster way of achieving the same thing.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to say: tuple(my_list[indexes])

Comment: @iCodez It does not. http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.5/Objects/abstract.c#l1479

Comment: @delnan - Interesting, I never knew that.  I'll delete my other comment because it is clearly wrong.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2.5/lib/module-operator.html#l2h-1193) (do you really have to use 2.5? It's dead and buried.)

Aside from being simpler, it also ought to be slightly faster due to being implemented in C. You can construct an `itemgetter` item once when you know which indices you want, then repeatedly call it on many lists. It still needs to copy N items and create a tuple each time, but it should do this as fast as reasonably possible.

Comment: +1 Very well, didn’t think about that. And it really is incredibly fast!

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question, but a nice solution, indeed!

Comment: @dorvak I disagree completely. OP wants to know how to implement this faster, and delnan gave him a way to implement this faster. That's purely an answer to the question

Comment: Burried 2.5 documentation link for [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2.5/lib/module-operator.html#l2h-1193). Call me the grave digger.

Comment: @Adam Smith Sry, missed that part completely!You'r right, and so is this answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

A tuple is an immutable sequence, so when it is created (and its memory allocated), it does need to know how much elements it will contain first. This means that when creating a tuple from a generator expression, the generator will have to be iterated completely first—and because generators can only be consumed once—and the elements need to be stored somewhere. So what’s happening can be compared with this:

```
tuple(list(generator))
```

Now, creating a list from a generator expression is slower than creating a list using a list comprehension, so you can save time by just creating a list using a list comprehension instead.

And if you don’t have a real reason to use a tuple, i.e. if you don’t require the immutability, you could also keep the list and not convert it to a tuple to save a bit more time.

Finally, no, there isn’t really a better way than to iterate your indexes and query the sequence for each. Even if the indexes are the same all the time, they still have to be evaluated for each list, so you have to repeat it anyway.

You can however save some more time if those indexes are actually fixed. Because a simple `(l[1], l[5], l[9])` will be a lot faster than anything else ;)

---

Here are some references from the source (using 3.4 here, but it should be similar in 2.x):

The creation of a tuple using the built-in `tuple()` function is done in the function [`PySequence_Tuple`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e33a036fd784/Objects/abstract.c#l1646).

If the argument is a list, then Python will handle that explicitely by calling [`PyList_AsTuple`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e33a036fd784/Objects/listobject.c#l2119) which essentially allocates a tuple of the list length and then just copies all items over.

Otherwise, it will create an iterator from the argument and first try to *guess* the length. As generators have no length, Python will use the default guess of `10` and allocate a tuple of that length—note that for your tuple, we have allocated 7 spaces too many. It will then iterate the iterator and assign each value to its place in the tuple. Afterwards, it will [*resize* the created tuple](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e33a036fd784/Objects/tupleobject.c#l839).

Now, the actual difference is likely the way list comprehensions work. List comprehensions are essentially a sequence of low-level list-appends. So that works similarly to the way the tuples are filled in `PySequence_Tuple`, described above. So from that, both methods would be equal. However, the difference with generator expressions is that they have an overhead of actually creating a generator (a sequence of yields) which needs to be iterated over. So all that is an extra which you avoid when having a list comprehension.

Comment: "it does need to know how much elements it will contain first" +1 for getting to the heart of the performance issue!

Comment: Unfortunately, it's also wrong. `PySequence_Tuple` (which `tuple(iterable)` redirects to) makes a single pass through the iterable. It starts with a guess of the length, and when that turns out too low, it uses the same re-allocation strategy as lists (even more aggressive = fast) but with the tuple's internal buffer. At the end, it gives back any excess space allocated, which *might* have for some overhead vs. lists but it does not iterate twice and it does not create a list of all elements before creating the tuple. See http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.5/Objects/abstract.c#l1479

Comment: @delnan I didn’t mean it to be equivalent to `tuple(list(generator))` but comparable, as during the iteration, the elements need to stored somewhere. It just happens to be that Python keeps the tuple it creates “mutable” at that point, so a separate list isn’t needed. I have adjusted the sentence to make that a bit more clear; and I also added some more explanation from the source.

Comment: Good. But that difference makes the primary source of suspected overhead (copying/iterating twice) disappear. There are other source of slow down, true, but I think any answer touching on them should be very clear to avoid misconceptions. In particular, it should mention which parts of the work you describe in the appendix would also happen in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, albeit slower than delnan's, is using `__getitem__` in cinjunction with `map`. However, even with the import-statement, delnan's version is faster.

```
In [36]: %timeit tuple(map(my_list.__getitem__,indexes))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 653 ns per loop


In [38]: %timeit itemgetter(*indexes)(my_list)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 292 ns per loop
```

Without ipython:

```
python -m timeit -s "indexes = (1,5,9); l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" "tuple(map(l.__getitem__,indexes))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.645 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "import operator" "indexes = (1,5,9); l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" "operator.itemgetter(*indexes)(l)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.463 usec per loop
```

Looks like the conversion to tuple is making the map-variant slower than the itemgetter-variant:

```
python -m timeit -s "indexes = (1,5,9); l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" "map(l.__getitem__,indexes)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.489 usec per loop
```

Comment: Using `map` and `__getitem__` is slower than the list comprehension solution too; and it works very similar in Python 2 too (`map` creates a list, and `__getitem__` is internally called when the list comprehension is evaluated too).